# Type Cover 2 not working with WIndows 10 (Release)

Tags: microsoft-surface, windows-10

I have a Surface Pro 2 with the Type Cover accessory.  After updating to Windows 10 yesterday, my type cover keys no longer work (though the mouse touch pad part seems just dandy).  I found [this help article](https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/hardware-and-drivers/troubleshoot-surface-keyboards?os=windows-10) from Microsoft and I have followed as much of these steps as makes sense based on the situation descriptions, but still have no luck.

Has anyone experienced this issue yet and has there been any type of firmware updates / touch pad updates / settings that need to be changed from default to make this work?

Comment: I would contact Microsoft with regards to that.  I have a SP3 which has no problem but it is different enough that that isn't a valid experience.  I do know there was a Windows 10 specific firmware update to deal with compatibility issues for the SP2 release in the last couple days you got that right?

Comment: @Ramhound - Well, I am posting on behalf of my wife who is out and about with the surface right now.  She called and informed me of the keyboard.  After I suggested looking at Windows Update, the firmware package was found (didn't see it previously).  This fixed the TypeCover.  I was going to wait for her to come home to post the KB number/run windows update as the solution, but if you know it and want to put it below as an answer, that would be awesome.

Comment: I don't know.  I just know the same article I read said the SP3 was also updated to address some issues.

Answer (score 0):

So, after suggesting checking for firmware updates, it does appear there was a firmware release July 23, 2015 that resolves this issue.  The step-by-step directions as well as the firmware release history for the Surface Pro 2 can be [found here](https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/install-update-activate/pro-2-update-history?os=windows-10).